# htaccess allow access to directory outside public

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to create a rewrite rule to allow users to access a directory outside the public directory.

so I have for example

app/
skins/
documents/
public/
   /index.php

I want my users to be able to access the documents folder while keeping public as my web root.

Is htaccess the best way to do this? if so, then how?

Comment: Off-topic: Why not put your `documents` folder inside `public`?

Comment: That would be an option however I'm dealing with a live legacy system and the paths are often hardcoded.

Comment: I could just add a symlink I know, but which is the better option? Plus I'd like to know if its possible via htaccess for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used a symbolic link to grant access the a none public directory via the URL. Using as Alias as GolexTrol suggested would also work but this is the method I used.

Answer (score 2):

Using `mod_alias` you can create an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

```
Alias /docs/ /your/path/to/documents
```

This allows you to browse to `www.example.com/docs` and get the content from the `documents` directory.

[mod_alias reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: Does the second value have to be the full path to that dir on the server or is it relative to the web root?

Comment: I think it can be relative as well if you leave out the leading `/`. But actually, I also like your own suggestion of making a symbolic link.